# ggplot2 3D Bar Plot

Tags: r, plot, 3d, ggplot2, bar-chart

I Know this sounds basic, but have a been searching for literally more than an hour now without success. I'm simply trying to plot a 3D bar plot in 'R' using the 'ggplot2' package. My dataframe looks something like this:

```
 x   y     z
t1   5   high
t1   2   low
t1   4   med
t2   8   high
t2   1   low
t2   3   med
t3  50   high
t3  12   med
t3  35   low
```

and I want to plot something like this on it:
[image]

Any help is more than appreciated!!

Comment: You should realize that R aficionados think of Excel as a rich source of examples of how _NOT_ to do things (properly) and that 3D barplots are one of the most deprecated strategies for communication of accurate quantitative information.

Comment: @BondedDust ha! yes, i do realise that. probably the reason why i cannot find any examples at all. but i still want to try, and any pointers from you will help… i just need to know how to add a third axis to my `geom_bar()`

Comment: This may be an avenue worth investigating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261760/how-to-generate-3-d-bar-graph-in-r

Comment: @Docconcoct thanks, but all the responses are for 2d plots!!

Comment: True. Just thought it was worth consideration.

Comment: From the author of rgl: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-September/141578.html and from @hadley: http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/prodplots.pdf

Comment: I don't think you can make a 3D barplot with `ggplot2`. Like exceeding the speed of light in our universe, there are just some things that are forbidden by the fundamental laws of the Hadleyverse. In any case, a line plot grouped by color will be much more informative. For example, with the data you listed above try this (where I've named the data frame dat): `ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, group=z, colour=z)) + geom_line() + geom_point()`.

Comment: @eipi10 Could not agree more. This comment of yours is actually worth posting as a decent answer IMO.

Comment: Does it have to be `ggplot`? (If not, take a peek at the examples in `?latticeExtra::panel.3dbars`.

Comment: @jbaums thank u J I'll check it now. No it doesn't have to be ggplot. Anything I can do in R would be just fine :)

Comment: @eipi10 thank you I'll try that in a second and post it as answer possibly;)

Comment: @tonytonov good to know I haven't tried it just yet as I've been away but will do in a second!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, 3D plots usually aren't a good choice (when other options are available) since they tend to give a distorted/obscured view of data.

That said, here's how you can plot your data as desired with `latticeExtra`:

```
d <- read.table(text=' x   y     z
t1   5   high
t1   2   low
t1   4   med
t2   8   high
t2   1   low
t2   3   med
t3  50   high
t3  12   med
t3  35   low', header=TRUE)

library(latticeExtra)

cloud(y~x+z, d, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='grey', 
      xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1), 
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")))
```

[image]

Comment: @maryam - just noticed the levels of `z` are ordered incorrectly. You can correct that by explicitly stating the level order when creating the factor.

Comment: oh yeah, it goes med -> low -> high instead of high -> med -> low thanks for the correction :)

Comment: What does `y~x+z' mean?

Comment: @DavideChicco.it - it says to plot `y` against `x` and `z` (where these are elements of data `d`).

Comment: @jbaums Thanks, I should have read the documentation. Another little help: how could I increase the dimensions of the sides of the parallelepipedon? Thanks!

Comment: The code raises error : Error Using Packet 1 Non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: To solve the error, also make x a factor.

Answer (score 0):

The {rayshader} package is another package that allows 3D visualisation - according to the author, it will only allow 3d visualisation for data that has indeed three dimension. Here based on a **tile plot**.

NB: the below required for me to install current GitHub versions of both the rayshader (v.0.33.3) and rgl (v.1.0.0) packages.

```
# devtools::install_github("tylermorganwall/rayshader") ## NB this will install a lot of dependencies
library(rayshader)
library(ggplot2)
d <- read.table(text=' x   y     z
t1   5   high
t1   2   low
t1   4   med
t2   8   high
t2   1   low
t2   3   med
t3  50   high
t3  12   med
t3  35   low', header=TRUE)

p <- ggplot(d, aes(x, z, fill = y)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_fermenter(type = "div", palette = "RdYlBu")

plot_gg(p)
render_movie(filename = "plot.gif")
```

[image]