# plot 8 rows x 12 columns in a 96-well plate format

Tags: r, pandas, plot, 3d, bar-chart

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
       a    b     c     d       e    f      g     h     i       j       k       l  
A   20.5    3.7   2.3   2.2     3.7  2.2    2.4   3.9   2.2     6.4     3.5     3.9
B   14.2    5.5   13.5  14.4    0.8  1.5    12.0  0.5   0.4     1.3     0.2     0.4
C   27.2    0.9   10.2  7.8     6.9  2.6    2.0   15.3  1.0      0.8    2.7     0.6
D   10.8    2.2   1.9   11.6    1.8  6.7    2.6   2.8   0.6      3.5    7.0     4.1
E   19.9    4.8   4.3    2.3    1.1  1.0    0.8   4.9   0.3      1.3    0.9     0.5
F   13.8    12.7  5.0   1.7     2.0  7.9    4.1   1.4   0.5      4.3    0.1     0.5
G   13.3    41.1  4.6   4.7     17.3 4.8    3.4   10.1  35.9    35.1    3.2     3.1
H   24.0    3.8   2.4   1.2      9.0 5.6    3.8    1.3  8.3      1.4    1.4     1.3
```

(8 row x 12 columns)

How do I plot them using pandas or R in a 8x12 format that would look like a '96-well format' bar chart?

Something like this but better than this excel chart:
[image]

thanks very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 3D Bar Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794236/ggplot2-3d-bar-plot)

Answer (score 1):

To do it easily in R, you need to "melt" your data to long format.

Read data:

```
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE,row.names=1,
text="
      a    b     c     d       e    f      g     h     i       j       k       l  
A   20.5    3.7   2.3   2.2     3.7  2.2    2.4   3.9   2.2     6.4     3.5     3.9
B   14.2    5.5   13.5  14.4    0.8  1.5    12.0  0.5   0.4     1.3     0.2     0.4
C   27.2    0.9   10.2  7.8     6.9  2.6    2.0   15.3  1.0      0.8    2.7     0.6
D   10.8    2.2   1.9   11.6    1.8  6.7    2.6   2.8   0.6      3.5    7.0     4.1
E   19.9    4.8   4.3    2.3    1.1  1.0    0.8   4.9   0.3      1.3    0.9     0.5
F   13.8    12.7  5.0   1.7     2.0  7.9    4.1   1.4   0.5      4.3    0.1     0.5
G   13.3    41.1  4.6   4.7     17.3 4.8    3.4   10.1  35.9    35.1    3.2     3.1
H   24.0    3.8   2.4   1.2      9.0 5.6    3.8    1.3  8.3      1.4    1.4     1.3
")
```

Using some tools from the tidyverse (but not using pipes):

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)
ddg <- gather(tibble::rownames_to_column(dd,"row"),
              key=col,value=value,-row)
```

Now the data look like this:

```
  row col value
1   A   a  20.5
2   B   a  14.2
3   C   a  27.2
4   D   a  10.8
...
```

Faceted plot with points (easier to compare magnitudes than in a 3D bar chart):

```
ggplot(ddg,aes(col,value))+geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~row,nrow=1)
```

Still faceted, but using bars rather than points:

```
ggplot(ddg,aes(col,value))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    facet_wrap(~row,nrow=1)
```

If you want to use intensity (I wouldn't recommend it):

```
ggplot(ddg,aes(col,row,fill=value))+geom_point(pch=21,size=6)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am still trying to absorb the code, will test and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Let's try and do it with Python.

First of all, you can use heatmap plot so you get intensity instead of bars with height.
This one can be easily made with [Seaborn heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.read_clipboard()   # just to get this data
sns.heatmap(df)
```

If you insist on a 3D bar plot (which, if I may express my opinion, is less clear due to plot orientation), you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

df = pd.read_clipboard            # just to get the data above

# Now we will need to flat out the matrix and treat it as a 1d vector:
x = list(range(df.shape[0])) * df.shape[1]  # the x axis labels\location
y = list(range(df.shape[1])) * df.shape[0]  # the y axis labels\location
z = [0] * len(X)                            # the initial height of the bars
dx = [1] * len(x)                           # the width of the bar
dy = [1] * len(y)                           # the depth of the bar
dz = df.values.flatten()                    # the bar heights - i.e. the data

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax.bar3d(x,y,z,dx,dy,dz)                    # plot in 3d
fig.show()
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: thanks I will test and let you know, I am very naive to pandas.

Comment: This does not involve high pandas-skills - especially the first solution is quite simple, though the second one does take some understanding in Python's Matplotlib (and its mediocre documentation). Feel free to ask follow ups :-)