# 3D bar plot with error bars in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I deeply appreciate the previous question and answers regarding 3D bar plot in R.

[ggplot2 3D Bar Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794236/ggplot2-3d-bar-plot)

However, the previous question and answers are not discussing how to plot "error bars" in the 3D plot.

I am interested in ploting following type of data.

```
data = structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("FALSE", 
"TRUE"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("FALSE", 
"TRUE"), class = "factor"), z = c(-0.1, 0.44, 0.35, 1.14), asymp.LCL = c(-0.11, 
0.35, 0.28, 0.94), asymp.UCL = c(-0.09, 0.54, 0.42, 1.34)), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "z", "asymp.LCL", "asymp.UCL"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")



data
      x     y     z asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
1 FALSE FALSE -0.10     -0.11     -0.09
2  TRUE FALSE  0.44      0.35      0.54
3 FALSE  TRUE  0.35      0.28      0.42
4  TRUE  TRUE  1.14      0.94      1.34
```

The answer from the previous question will produce a 3D bar plot "without error bars."

```
library(latticeExtra)
cloud(z~x+y, data = data, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet='grey', 
      xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1), 
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")))
```

[image: image generated with library latticeExtra]

I would also appreciate if there is any other solution without using the library latticeExtra.

Please let me know any advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Just my opinion, but if you add also errorbars to that plot it will highly probaly become quite hard to digest for your readers. Maybe consider a faceted or a dodgled bar-plot.

Comment: I strongly recommend a simple 2D plot like: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(d, aes(x, z, ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL, fill = y)) + geom_col(position = position_dodge(0.75), width = 0.75) + geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(0.75), width = 0.5)`

Comment: Or `ggplot(d, aes('a', z, ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL)) + geom_col() + geom_errorbar(width = 0.5) + facet_grid(x~y, labeller = label_both)`

Comment: @ Jaap @ Axeman: Thanks for your advice. I agree that usually 2D plots can be better representations. Faceted plot could be a very good alternative. However, my models have naturally perpendicular axes, and my boss wants to check them with 3D plots.

Comment: Please let me know if anyone has any other suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned to how to add layers in the library latticeExtra.

```
data = structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("FALSE", 
"TRUE"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("FALSE", 
"TRUE"), class = "factor"), z = c(-0.1, 0.44, 0.35, 1.14), asymp.LCL = c(-0.11, 
0.35, 0.28, 0.94), asymp.UCL = c(-0.09, 0.54, 0.42, 1.34), asymp.interval = c(0.024, 
0.191, 0.144, 0.402), SE = c(0.006, 0.049, 0.037, 0.103), z_SE = c(-0.094, 
0.489, 0.387, 1.243)), .Names = c("x", "y", "z", "asymp.LCL", 
"asymp.UCL", "asymp.interval", "SE", "z_SE"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
zlim = c(-1, 2)

cloud(z~x+y, data = data, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet ='grey',
      xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col="black"),
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"))
      , zlim = zlim) +
    as.layer(cloud(
        z_SE~x+y, data = data, col ='black',
        par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"))
        , zlim = zlim, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, zlab = NULL
    )) +
    as.layer(cloud(
        value~x+y, data = bind_rows(select(data, x, y), gather((data %>% select(x, y, z, z_SE))[1,], z, z_SE, key = "key", value = "value"))
        , col ='black', panel.3d.cloud = panel.3dscatter, type = "l"
        , par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"))
        , zlim = zlim, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, zlab = NULL
    )) +
    as.layer(cloud(
        value~x+y, data = bind_rows(select(data, x, y), gather((data %>% select(x, y, z, z_SE))[2,], z, z_SE, key = "key", value = "value"))
        , col ='black', panel.3d.cloud = panel.3dscatter, type = "l"
        , par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"))
        , zlim = zlim, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, zlab = NULL
    )) +
    as.layer(cloud(
        value~x+y, data = bind_rows(select(data, x, y), gather((data %>% select(x, y, z, z_SE))[3,], z, z_SE, key = "key", value = "value"))
        , col ='black', panel.3d.cloud = panel.3dscatter, type = "l"
        , par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"))
        , zlim = zlim, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, zlab = NULL
    )) +
    as.layer(cloud(
        value~x+y, data = bind_rows(select(data, x, y), gather((data %>% select(x, y, z, z_SE))[4,], z, z_SE, key = "key", value = "value"))
        , col ='black', panel.3d.cloud = panel.3dscatter, type = "l"
        , par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent"))
        , zlim = zlim, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, zlab = NULL
    ))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsmjn.png)

Please let me know if you know any other solution.

Thanks.