# 3d Stacked bar plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `mydf` as shown below. I want to plot a stacked 3d plot (as shown in sample plot below) where A, C, G, T columns are represented by bars (years in the sample plot). Length column ranges from 18 to 34 for each file.name and want them to be on the `Gas Type` axis as in example plot, then I finally want `file.name` column to be on `country axis` as in sample plot below. How can I get this plotted in R? Thanks for your help.

[image: Sample plot]

```
  mydf <-  structure(list(file.name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("merged_read_counts", "DCL1_VF_1_GAGTGG_L008_R1_001", 
    "DCL1_VF_2_GGTAGC_L008_R1_001", "DCL2_VF_1_ACTGAT_L008_R1_001", 
    "DCL2_VF_2_ATGAGC_L008_R1_001", "DCLd_SSHADV1_1_AGTTCC_L008_R1_001", 
    "DCLd_SSHADV1_2_ATGTCA_L008_R1_001", "DCLd_SSHADV1_3_CCGTCC_L008_R1_001", 
    "DCLd_SSHV2L_1_GTAGAG_L008_R1_001", "DCLd_SSHV2L_2_GTCCGC_L008_R1_001", 
    "DCLd_SSHV2L_3_GTGAAA_L008_R1_001", "DCLd_VF_1_GTGGCC_L008_R1_001", 
    "DCLd_VF_2_GTTTCG_L008_R1_001", "DCLd_VF_3_CGTACG_L008_R1_001", 
    "WT_SSHADV1_1_GGCTAC_L008_R1_001", "WT_SSHADV1_2_CTTGTA_L008_R1_001", 
    "WT_SSHADV1_3_AGTCAA_L008_R1_001", "WT_SSHV2L_1_GCCAAT_L008_R1_001", 
    "WT_SSHV2L_2_CAGATC_L008_R1_001", "WT_SSHV2L_3_ACTTGA_L008_R1_001", 
    "WT_SSHV2L_4_GATCAG_L008_R1_001", "WT_SSHV2L_5_TAGCTT_L008_R1_001", 
    "WT_VF_1_ATCACG_L008_R1_001", "WT_VF_2_CGATGT_L008_R1_001", "WT_VF_3_TTAGGC_L008_R1_001", 
    "WT_VF_4_TGACCA_L008_R1_001", "WT_VF_5_ACAGTG_L008_R1_001"), class = "factor"), 
        length = c(18L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 19L), A = c(2294436L, 
        2588528L, 52104L, 47190L, 103378L, 59269L), C = c(1501040L, 
        2838174L, 35888L, 93922L, 38132L, 31912L), G = c(2106623L, 
        1714702L, 80765L, 64930L, 129040L, 161517L), T = c(5065628L, 
        7462881L, 62174L, 87905L, 274783L, 110125L)), .Names = c("file.name", 
    "length", "A", "C", "G", "T"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 18L, 19L, 
    58L, 59L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please see [Stephen Few's analysis](http://www.perceptualedge.com/example3.php) of the design problems of 3D bar graphs and the alternatives he is suggesting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2 3D Bar Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794236/ggplot2-3d-bar-plot)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think 3d bar plots are available in ggplot([ggplot2 3D Bar Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794236/ggplot2-3d-bar-plot)).

I would suggest grouped, stacked barplots instead. Something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(mydf,id.vars=c("file.name","length"))
ggplot(df, aes(x = file.name, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ length)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this plot looks really cluttered with my big data.