# How to create stack bar charts that look cubic (3D) in R ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I want the stack charts as coded below but I want them to look cubic (attached). Is it even possible in R?

```
set.seed(123)
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3))
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen", "T") , 3)
value <- abs(rnorm(12, 0 ,15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
 
# Stacked
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
    geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", alpha = 0.7, width = 0.3) + theme_classic()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Definitely possible in R - likely deliberately impossible with ggplot. Possible duplicate [ggplot2 3D Bar Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26794236/903061)

Comment: @GregorThomas I saw that! I think that poster were trying to create separate stacks 3D the old school way. I want stacked bars but just want it 3D or cubic looking for aesthetics.

Comment: Yes, but the result has 3d aesthetics. So yours is a special case of that answer where all the Z values are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with the unpublished [ggrgl](https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggrgl) package, among others. Applying this to your example, we have:

```r
remotes::install_github('coolbutuseless/devout')
remotes::install_github('coolbutuseless/devoutrgl')
remotes::install_github('coolbutuseless/ggrgl', ref='main')

library(rgl)
library(devout)
library(devoutrgl)
library(ggrgl)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie, z =2,
                 extrude_face_fill = condition)) + 
    geom_bar_z(position="stack", stat="identity", width = 0.3, extrude = TRUE,
               color = "black") + 
  theme_classic()

devoutrgl::rgldev()
p
invisible(dev.off())
```

The result is a rotatable 3D ggplot:

[image]

Comment: Do you think that there is a chance to animate such bars. Kind of fill empty white bars with the color?

Comment: @TarJae it might be possible with rgl's `play3d` function - I haven't explored that properly.