# How to plot 3 variables (BMI, weight gain, and relative risk) in one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am having trouble with a question for my assignment. I am being asked to make a better plot of the data in this paper.

[image]

I was provided with the first few steps.

These commands enter the data:

```
chd.wt<-matrix(c(3, 2.9, 3.1, 4, 6, 
    1.1, 1.2, 2, 3, 3.8,
    1, 1.2, 1.1,  1.1, 3.2,
    1, 1.2, 1.2, 1, 2,
    0, 0, 0, 0.8, 2), byrow=T, ncol=5)

colnames(chd.wt)<-c("<19", "19-20.3", "20.4-21.5", "21.6-23.2", ">23.3")
rownames(chd.wt)<-c("gained 20 kg", "gained 11-20 kg", "gained 5-11 kg",
 "lost 5 to gained 5 kg", "lost 5+ kg")
```

Here's the matrix we have now:

```
chd.wt
```

We want to plot the columns of the matrix, which we can pull out like this.  This first column is those with BMI of 19 or below:

```
chd.wt[,1]
```

```
chd.wt[,2]
```

```
colnames(chd.wt)
```

```
rownames(chd.wt)
```

Here's the start of a mosaic style command.

```
xyplot(chd.wt[,1] +chd.wt[,2] ~ 1:5, type=c("p", "l"),
        scales=list(x=list(at=1:5, labels=rownames(chd.wt) )
                    ), xlab="Weight change", auto.key=T, ylab="RR")
```

```
xyplot(chd.wt[1,] +chd.wt[2,] ~ 1:5, type=c("p", "l"),
        scales=list(x=list(at=1:5, labels=colnames(chd.wt) )
                    ), xlab="BMI", auto.key=T, ylab="RR")
```

```
xyplot(chd.wt[1,] +chd.wt[2,] ~ 1:5, type=c("p", "l"),
        scales=list(x=list(at=1:5, labels=rownames(chd.wt))
                    ), xlab="BMI", auto.key=T, ylab="RR")
```

I was thinking a ggplot, but I don't how to get started.

Comment: Not exactly the same but these package [ggridges examples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/gallery.html) might give you some ideas.

Comment: ggplot doesn't support 3d column charts (or didn't last time I looked into it) because the main author(s) consider them a poor choice for basically all data types - they are generally hard to interpret correctly (or rather, easy to interpret wrongly) so there are better choices.  That said, I'm sure there are packages that DO allow it - I'll see what I can find.

Comment: You have two categorical variables and one continuous, so I think a heatmap (coloured tiles) could work - you could use a tile border for the healthy BMI range categories.  Otherwise, possibly just a simple column chart, faceted by the age category?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Actually there is a library above ggplot2 that allows 3D and animated plotting for such cases. Kindly see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75049043/5043424)

Answer (score 3):

The key step here is *reshaping* your matrix into a data frame with three columns: one for BMI category, one for weight loss category, and one for relative risk. You can do this quite easily using Tidyverse functions:

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot_df <- chd.wt %>%
  as.data.frame(check.names = FALSE) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = 'Weight change') %>%
  mutate(`Weight change` = factor(`Weight change`, rev(`Weight change`))) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = 'BMI', values_to = 'Relative Risk') %>%
  mutate(BMI = factor(BMI, unique(BMI)))
```

Now we have the following data frame, which makes it very easy to plot in `ggplot`:

```r
plot_df
#> # A tibble: 25 x 3
#>    `Weight change` BMI       `Relative Risk`
#>    <fct>           <fct>               <dbl>
#>  1 gained 20 kg    <19                   3  
#>  2 gained 20 kg    19-20.3               2.9
#>  3 gained 20 kg    20.4-21.5             3.1
#>  4 gained 20 kg    21.6-23.2             4  
#>  5 gained 20 kg    >23.3                 6  
#>  6 gained 11-20 kg <19                   1.1
#>  7 gained 11-20 kg 19-20.3               1.2
#>  8 gained 11-20 kg 20.4-21.5             2  
#>  9 gained 11-20 kg 21.6-23.2             3  
#> 10 gained 11-20 kg >23.3                 3.8
#> # ... with 15 more rows
```

Rather than having a 3D bar plot, we can present these three dimensions of information as a simple heatmap:

```r
ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = BMI, y = `Weight change`, fill = `Relative Risk`)) +
  geom_tile(color = 'black', linewidth = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  coord_equal(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line())
```

[image]

If you are constrained to using black-and-white, simply change `scale_fill_viridis_c()` to `scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'black')`, which gives you:

[image]

Note that a clear pattern can be discerned, with higher relative risk being seen in higher BMI ranges and in larger weight gain categories, while there is a very low relative risk in the weight loss category. This type of visualization is useful if you want your chart to show the pattern of relationship between your variables.

If you want to be able to show exact values in graphical form, with less emphasis on the overall pattern, a faceted bar plot may be best:

```r
ggplot(plot_df, aes(BMI, `Relative Risk`)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(`Weight change`~.) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Although, even in this case, it might be better to just add actual values to the heatmap if the specific value of Relative Risk is very important:

```r
ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = BMI, y = `Weight change`, fill = `Relative Risk`)) +
  geom_tile(color = 'black', linewidth = 0.3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = `Relative Risk`, color = `Relative Risk` > 3.5),
            size = 5, fontface = 2) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'black') +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'white'), guide = 'none') +
  coord_equal(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is nice, comprehensive and even considers printability with the greyscale options.  Can you say how you would mark "healthy BMI" ranges (the shaded columns in the original example) - I was thinking underline the text of the value, or use a tile border maybe, but I don't know if there's a better way.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen you can outline the tiles with a specific color. From looking at the original plot, the legend / plot caption doesn't make a lot of sense, because some of the columns with the same BMI are different colors. You would need to specify a new column in `plot_df` that labels each measure as 'Healthy' or 'Not healthy' based on whatever criteria you choose - let's call it `Weight`. Then, if you change your `geom_tile` call to  `geom_tile(aes(color = Weight), linewidth = 0.3)` You will get the healthy / non-healthy cells outlined in different colors.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a possibility to draw the desired plot. Though this kind of graph is **highly discouraged**. The idea is as follows (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26822348/5043424) answer):

You need to prepare your data first:

```
library(tidyverse)
chd.wt2<-
chd.wt %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  `colnames<-`(colnames(chd.wt)) %>% 
  mutate(rn = rownames(chd.wt)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rn) %>% 
  transmute(x = factor(rn, levels = rev(rownames(chd.wt)), ordered = T),
  z = factor(name, levels = colnames(chd.wt), ordered = T),
  y = value)
```

Here is the code to plot

```
library(latticeExtra)
cloud(y~x+z, chd.wt2, panel.3d.cloud=panel.3dbars, col.facet=c('grey', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'blue'), 
      xbase=0.4, ybase=0.4, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, col=1), 
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(col = "transparent")))
```

[image]

Of course you can set (adjust) necessary colours, orders of factors' levels etc.

Comment: I was going to add this to my answer, but the result is worse than the plot in the original article. The labels are not justified correctly, there are no gridlines, the lines are pixelated etc. Still, useful to have as an option I guess.